# Subfig no space between figures and double brackets

Tags: subfloats

I followed the instructions here to make subfigures
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats

However there were no space between the figure and I got double brackets for the captions. I cannot find any instruction on the Internet. I hope anyone can help me here.

My code is like this

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \subfloat[a]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth,height=15em]{appendix/1.jpg}}
  \subfloat[b]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[height=15em]{solution.jpg}}     
  \caption[The short caption]{The long caption}
  \label{fig:preparation}
\end{figure}
```

------- Update --------

Problem solved! For the spacing I used `\qquad` and for double brackets, I found out that I have both packages `subfigure` and `subfig` enabled. I deleted package `subfigure` then I get single brackets as expected.

Thank you all for helping me solve this problem!

Comment: where do you get this? In the actual caption, when referring? Try to be a little more specific and add a minimal working example illustrating the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Also, you are linking to the *Wrap text around figures* section, which looks like a mistake to me.

Comment: Thank you @wh1t3! I've updated my question with my codes. Hope it looks fine this time.

Comment: Maybe the width and height options interfere with the subfig package? Try to remove them, and then maybe add `\hfill` between the two figures.

Comment: I am affraid I still don't see the issue. When I compile your code (after changing `textwidth` to `\textwidth` and adding `graphicx` with the `demo` option (since I don't have your pictures) I get the following output: http://i.imgur.com/BwUIV.png , which seems fine to me. If there is a problem there, can you explain what it is? If not, there is a problem on your end that the example does not illustrate.

Comment: @wh1t3, yeah, it is `\textwidth`. I got the error messages when compiling my code `! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \sf@counterlist \begin{document}` and `!Missing = iserted for \ifnum.<to be read again>. ...`

Comment: @Dror, `\hfill` or `\ppuad` works. But the double brackets are still there.

Comment: @clarezoe Without a real minimal example like the one I just posted in my answer, we can't solve your double brackets problem.  Have you redefined `\thesubfigure` somewhere?

Answer (score 8):

The syntax of the `subfloat` command is

```
\subfloat[list-of-floats-caption][subcaption]{body}
```

The `subcaption` part is *not* used for the numbering of the subcaptions (which is done automatically).  You should only use the first optional argument if you need a different caption inside the list of floats.

So to get just (a) and (b) you should use:

```
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=.5textwidth,height=15em]{appendix/1.jpg}}
```

You need to insert space manually between the two `\subfloat` commands.  You can do this with `\qquad` or any other horizontal spacing command such as `\hfil` or `\hspace{}`.

Here's a minimal example to show what I did.  (In future, you should ask your questions by providing an full example like this instead of just a fragment.)  Your "double" brackets are coming from somewhere else.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \subfloat[A sub caption]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth,height=15em]{appendix/1.jpg}}
  \qquad
  \subfloat[A sub caption]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth,height=15em]{solution.jpg}}     
  \caption[The short caption]{The long caption}
  \label{fig:preparation}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you @alan-munn! For the subcption, a and b I used are for captions which will be replaced by other texts. But I still get the double brackets `((a)) Caption a` and `((b)) Caption b`.

Comment: Thank you for your demonstration. What do you mean by "full example"? Do you mean I should use `\documentclass{aricle}...` and `\usepackage` as well? The code I've provided is pretty much I have, and others are not relevant.

Comment: @clarezoe Yes.  Clearly *some* of the other code *is* relevant, since my example has no extra brackets and yours does. By providing a complete document (with all the unnecessary stuff removed) it's easier for someone here to just compile your example rather than have to make their own. The process of doing so can also solve your problem as it seems to have.  How were we to know that you were loading both the `subfig` and `subfigure` packages without a complete example?

Comment: by "other codes" I meant the package setting, and other chapters, maybe the complete code you mean should be everything that can reproduce the problem. This was my first time posting a questions here and it was very urgent I didn't have time to read all the details and rules. I apologies for that. For `subfigure` is included in the template I'm using and it was in a separate file which was rather difficult to find out. Thanks you again for your kind help and patience. I will definitely do better next time :)

Comment: @Clarezoe There's no need to apologize. And, yes, I meant the smallest code that could reproduce the problem, not your entire source document.  Welcome to the site, and please don't take my comments as enforcing "the rules". There aren't really any rules, but questions with minimal examples will likely get faster and more accurate responses than those that post only fragments. And you'll find that we're a pretty friendly bunch here.

Comment: I totally agree! I've been active in some forums helping people and I understand a minimal examples is very important and I appreciate any help and responses I got here. You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The way to get rid of the double brackets and turn ((a)) into (a) is to simply include the subcaption package.

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
```