# How to add horizontal space between two centered subfigures?

Tags: floats

I have the following LaTex code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}

     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{imgs/high_accuracy_Low_precision.png}
    \caption{low accuracy, low precision}
  \end{subfigure}
  %
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}

    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{imgs/high_precision_Low_accuracy.png}
    \caption{low accuracy, high precision}
  \end{subfigure}
  \label{fig:4foldcross}
\end{figure}
```

The output result is:

[image]

How can I make some space in between these images?

Comment: Take a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42975/46716

Comment: @MaartenDhondt Thanks. The answer with the most votes, in the link you provided, has the solutions. The answer did not come up on Google for me, and I didn't think about looking for "how to remove space" as it is the opposite.

Comment: Same solution but different question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43284/how-to-distribute-narrow-expressions-along-a-line

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31812/4778