# Subfigure problem caption

Tags: floats, subfloats

so I'm having this stupid problem with the subfigure captions.[image]

The code I'm using is:

```
  \usepackage{subfigure}
  \begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
 \centering
  \subfloat[NACA airfoil 0012]{

    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{12}}
  \subfloat[NACA airfoil 4420]{

    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{4420}}
  \subfloat[NACA airfoil 4414]{

    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{4414}}
      \subfloat[NACA airfoil 5122]{

    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{5122}}
 \caption{QBlade wind turbine blades}

 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

thanks everyone!

Comment: Please specify your question. Is spacing the problem? Could you complete your code to a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), the beginning between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` is missing.

Comment: Is this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31812/subfig-no-space-between-figures-and-double-brackets?rq=1) related to your problem? Maybe a duplicate...

Comment: Yes, Is just about spacing. There's nothing more. Just 
    \documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,11pt]{article}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General comment: The `subfigure` package is deprecated. Don't use it! Instead, use the `subfig` package.

My main suggestion is that you use three `\hfill` directives to maximize the separation between the four subfigures.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,11pt,demo]{article} 
    % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\includegraphics' macro
\usepackage{subfig}   % for `\subfloat` macro

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure*}[h!]
  \subfloat[NACA airfoil 0012]{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{12}}\hfill
  \subfloat[NACA airfoil 4420]{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{4420}}\hfill
  \subfloat[NACA airfoil 4414]{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{4414}}\hfill
  \subfloat[NACA airfoil 5122]{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{5122}}

  \caption{QBlade wind turbine blades}

\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subcaption` that makes it easier to detach the width of the subfigure from the width of the enclosing subfloat.

Here I use subfloats one fifth of the line width (so the graphics are scaled to 0.3 instead of 0.15).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-9x16}
\caption{NACA airfoil 0012}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-9x16}
\caption{NACA airfoil 4420}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-9x16}
\caption{NACA airfoil 4414}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-9x16}
\caption{NACA airfoil 5122}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{QBlade wind turbine blades}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]